# How to make an activity inaccessible or locked?

Tags: java, android

I am about to make a quiz application which would consist of multiple levels. Now each level is a java class and if the user completed what has to be done on the first java class like for an example answering a question, now the user proceeds to the second java class(next question).

My problem:
I don't know how to make the first java class inaccessible after proceeding to the next java class.

What i tried:
i tried searching it online and i can't find any answer, maybe i just can't get the right term for it.

Comment: You mean, if you click backwards you dont want to go previous level ? Just implement some custom logic to handle navigation

Comment: would that also work even if i relaunched the app, like if i proceed to 2nd java class then relaunch the app?

Answer (score 0):

on each level first check previous level is completed or not.
on successful completion of level set data in preference such level-1=true
before calling next level check previous level value is true or not, if true then go ahead, give error otherwise.

```
//set level value to true after completion of level
setBoolean(getApplicationContext(),"Level1",true);

//check previous level value when calling next level
level2.onClick{
   if(getBoolean(getApplicationContext(),"Level1")){
       //start next level
   } else {
       //give error
   }
}



public static void setBoolean(Context context, String key, Boolean Value) {
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor sEdit = sharedPreferences.edit();
    sEdit.putBoolean(key, Value);
    sEdit.commit();
}

public static Boolean getBoolean(Context context, String key) {
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    Boolean value = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, false);
    return value;
}
```